# How to pass arraylist values from my activity to custom adapter?

Tags: android, visual-studio, gridview, android-recyclerview

I am creating a sample news application. I stored rss feed in hashlist and put it on an array list. I have a custom rcycler view adapter. I want to pass this values to adapter and display in grid form. But now I am not able to pass and display values.

```
  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // rss link url
        String rss_url = args[0];

        // list of rss items
        rssItems = rssParser.getRSSFeedItems(rss_url);

        // looping through each item
        for (RSSItem item : rssItems) {
            // creating new HashMap
            if (item.link.toString().equals(""))
                break;
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            String givenDateString = item.pubdate.trim();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy 
    HH:mm:ss Z");
            try {
                Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM 
   yyyy - hh:mm a", Locale.US);
                item.pubdate = sdf2.format(mDate);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            map.put(TAG_TITLE, item.title);
            map.put(TAG_LINK, item.link);
            map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, item.description);
            map.put(TAG_PUB_DATE, item.pubdate); // If you want parse the 
     date

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            rssItemList.add(map);
        }

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
  findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                // set a GridLayoutManager with default vertical orientation 
    and 2 number of columns
                GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new 
    GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // set 
     LayoutManager to RecyclerView
                //  call the constructor of CustomAdapter to send the 
     reference and data to Adapter
                CustomAdapter customAdapter = new 
      CustomAdapter(RSSFeedActivity.this, rssItemList, new String[] 
   {TAG_LINK, TAG_TITLE, TAG_DESCRIPTION,TAG_PUB_DATE});
                recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
```

Recyclleview Adapter:

```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
   import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
         public class CustomAdapter extends  
       RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {
    ArrayList rssItemList;
      String [] from;

Context context;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList rssItemList,String[] from) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rssItemList = rssItemList;
    this.from=from;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // infalte the item Layout
    View v = 
   LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, 
     parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {



    holder.name.setText(rssItemList.indexOf(0)); //Not working
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rssItemList.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // init the item view's
    TextView name;
    TextView image;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // get the reference of item view's
        name = (TextView) 
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_text1);
        image = (TextView) 
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.android_gridview_text2);
    }
        }
```

Rssitem Class

```
public class RSSItem {

public String title;
public String link;
public String description;
public String pubdate;
public String guid;

public RSSItem(String title, String link, String description, String 
 pubdate, String guid) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.description = description;
    this.pubdate = pubdate;
    this.guid = guid;
     }
  }
```

How do I solve this issue? Please check my customer adapter code.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that rssItemList have data then onBindViewHolder should like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.name.setText(rssItemList.get(position).getTitle().toString());
//rssItemList.get(position).getYourMethod().toString()
 }
```

Comment: use toString() instead of that

Comment: Now i am able to display.But i w have 4 key pair values,i want to display each value in seperate text fields.Like title,description..etc.pls check my code

Comment: make holder according that. refer http://www.sanktips.com/2017/11/15/android-recyclerview-with-custom-adapter-example/

Comment: I have  texview in my holder.Will update than in code.One for show title,one for discription,one for time.In curre code i given only one text filed.My requirment is need to display title in first text view.But now title,description,time everything showing in same textview

Comment: holder.name.setText(rssItemList.get(position).getTitle().toString());

Comment: holder.description.setText(rssItemList.get(position).getDescription().toString());

Comment: like that way use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197021/discussion-between-learner-and-sasikumar).

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is correct but this is not correct `holder.name.setText(rssItemList.indexOf(0));`

Instead use something like this ;

```
HashMap item = rssItemList.get(position)
holder.name.setText(item.get("title"))
```

The indexOf() method is `Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element` it's for finding index, and you just want to have the RssItem of your list.
It's why I'm using get and the variable `position` in the `onBindViewHolder`

EDIT : Your array is full of HashMap, I have updated the code in the first line you get your HashMap and in the second line you get the variable who has the key "title", you can get the other value if you put "link", "description" or pubDate" instead

Comment: Required : com.journaldev.androidrssfeedtutorial.RSSitem
found : java.lang.object.Getting this error

Comment: Can u pls help.Still i am getting same error.And pls check my Rss item class.Should i change anything there?

Answer (score 1):

try below code for getting value from array list

- holder.name.setText(rssItemList.get(postion).get(TAG_TITLE))

Comment: When i try this line i am getting error cannot resolve postion and TAG TITLE

Comment: You can take position from second argument of onBindViewHolder. And TAG_TITLE is key your hashmap key which you want to display. in textview.